# Can we create more than one package in single Java file?

Tags: java, package

Can we create more than one package in a single `.java` file? Like:

```
package parent;
package parent.child;   // parent exists already from the previous command

package dada.papa.beta; // dada & papa does not exits but -> for creating beta java will automatically create dada & papa


public class b{ 

    /* see the ReadMe.txt  file 
        here i am just creatign packages;
    */
        public static void main(String[] args) {}
}
```

I just wanted to practice making lots of packages and sub packages in a single go.

Error:

```
Unix-Box ~/making_sub_packages$    javac -d . b.java 

b.java:2: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package parent.child;   
^
b.java:4: error: class, interface, or enum expected
package dada.papa.beta; 
^
2 errors
```

Comment: What would be the purpose of this? How would you use it? How should it work?

Comment: A class can only be in one package. Same as a file can only be in one folder *(ignoring hard links)*.

Comment: @Pshemo the only purpose was that i am lazy and i just wanted to create more then one packages in a single go, i didn't want this file to be in any package, but just make some independent packages so i could practice how to make them, without creating new file for each one of them, hope you understand my pain

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do that.

The package statement must be the first line in the source file. There can be only one package statement in each source file, and it applies to all types in the file. You can read more here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/createpkgs.html